# reshaping data frame into contingency table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, contingency

I have an series of  excel files like the following which contain a contingency table :

```
         cns random
H3k       12  682
Not_H3k  343  30222
```

when i use 'gdata' library to read this file using this command, it gives the following table which is not contingency table anymore:

```
random <- read.xls ("analysis.xlsx", sheet = 1, header = TRUE)

              X    cns   random
        1     UTR  12    682
        2 Not_UTR 343  30222
```

i want to run fisher test on this data, how can i reshape this data.frame data into a contingency table format?

Comment: What happens if you use `read.xls("analysis.xlsx", sheet = 1, header = TRUE, row.names = 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read.xls allows any arguments for read.table. Specifically, you can specify the number of a column that contains the row names. So you could use

```
random <- read.xls ("analysis.xlsx", sheet = 1, header = TRUE, row.names=1)
```

and proceed with the test

Comment: Tnx, it worked, its strange,row.names is not mentioned as an argument in 
?gdata::read.xls!!     is there also a way to reshape a data frame which is already loaded into R into contingency table?!

Comment: Look at the explanation for the ellipsis argument for read.xls...there's an implicit suggestion to look at read.table for other possible arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fisher test with the dataframe that you have:

```
random = structure(list(X = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("Not_UTR", 
"UTR"), class = "factor"), cns = c(12L, 343L), random = c(682L, 
30222L)), .Names = c("X", "cns", "random"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

random
        X cns random
1     UTR  12    682
2 Not_UTR 343  30222

fisher.test(random[,-1])

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  ddf[, -1] 
p-value = 0.1433
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1 
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7892877 2.7613943 
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  1.550284
```